# iframe not take up full space depending on doctype

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have an iframe like this:

```
<body><iframe id="tree" name="tree" src="foobar.html" frameborder="0" marginheight="5" marginwidth="5" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto"></iframe></body>
```

With this it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But with this it only shows as like 100px high:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I also tried appliy css style height: 100% to iframe and body, but that didn't do anything.

How can I get the iframe to take up full page but still use the

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: in HTML5 iframe is deprecated.

Comment: @PerfectDark I remembered wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML 5 the value of width & height attribute of an `<iframe>` must be defined in `px` not `%`

It's probably parsing your `100%` into `100px` ..  simply tweak the `width/height` values in `px` to your needs and you're good ..

Comment: This is true, but what if you want it to take up all the space it can and resize with the window?

Answer (score 0):

Make your CSS class with `position:absolute` or use `style="position:absolute;`